# React hook form | Browsers auto fill. How to make so that input knows about the data from auto fill

Tags: react-hook-form, password-autofill

How to make so that input knows about the data from auto fill? You can go to codesandbox, add some auto-fill data, refresh a page and see this problem. Is there any idea how to fight it?

It doesn't work:

- autoComplete="off"
- autoComplete="new-password"

autoComplete="new-password"

There is a code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-mantine-npvcof?file=/src/App.js

This thing we get at first:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering that I use the mantine lib this way helped me

https://ui.mantine.dev/component/floating-label-input

Anyway, I think it can help to come up with an option how to work it out

Answer (score 0):

I had issue like this with matterial UI, and the reason was that I didn't wrapped Input with FormControl component.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can use ***register*** to register the attributes, instead of having ***onChange*** as an attribute for instance an input.So we can use ***onChange*** inside the ***register*** method!

DO NOT THIS:

```
<input
...
onChange={handleInputChangeFunction}
...
/>
```

DO THIS:

```
<Input
...
{...register('inputName', {
...,
onChange(event) {
   handleInputChangeFunction(event);
},
...
/>
```

it should work perfectly fine!